# Using OpenGL4.x on MFC SDI

Tags: c++, opengl, mfc

I'm trying to learn OpenGL 4.x using the 8th edition of [Red Book](http://www.opengl-redbook.com/). Since the moment I don't want to use glew, freeglut or other 3rd party stuff, I've written some basic code myself.

Using MFC I've extended CView adding:

```
// OnCreate
m_pDC = new CClientDC( this );
m_nNumFD = ChoosePixelFormat( m_pDC->GetSafeHdc(), &m_pfd );
SetPixelFormat( m_pDC->GetSafeHdc(), m_nNumFD, &m_pfd );
m_hglrc = wglCreateContext( m_pDC->GetSafeHdc() );
wglMakeCurrent( m_pDC->GetSafeHdc(), m_hglrc );
glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
glClearColor( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
glClearDepth( 1.0f );

// OnDraw
CGLEntTest  entita;
wglMakeCurrent( m_pDC->GetSafeHdc(), m_hglrc );
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
glBegin( GL_LINES );
    glColor3d( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    glVertex2d( 0.0, 0.0 );
    glVertex2d( 1.0, 1.0 );
glEnd();
SwapBuffers( pDC->GetSafeHdc() );
wglMakeCurrent( NULL, NULL );

// OnSize
CView::OnSize( nType, cx, cy );

// TODO: Add your message handler code here
m_RettVis.left = 0;
m_RettVis.bottom = cy;
m_RettVis.right = cx;
m_RettVis.top = 0;
m_dAR = (double)cx / (double)cy;
glViewport( 0, 0, cx, cy );
wglMakeCurrent( m_pDC->GetSafeHdc(), m_hglrc );
glPushMatrix();
glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho( -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0 );
glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glPopMatrix();

// stdafx.h
#include <gl\GL.h>
#include <gl\GLU.h>
// stdafx.cpp
#pragma comment( lib, "glu32.lib" )
#pragma comment( lib, "opengl32.lib" )
```

This basic code works well and I manage to see the line correctly.

Now, the RedBook (as every other modern OpenGL book) is based on shaders, so I've created CGLEntTest and started to write:

```
glGenVertexArrays( NumVAOs, VAOs );
glBindVertexArray( VAOs[Triangles] );
```

but Microsoft VS 2010 says that it cannot find those functions.
I guess that they're included in some header that I've not included but I can't find it on my system.

My questions are: 1) Where I can find those includes? 2) Is it possible to learn new OpenGL without using Glew/FreeGlut/blabla, reading only RedBook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows opengl library support low opengl version;

If your video card and drivers support opengl 4, you need get function adress (glGenVertexArrays, glBindVertexArray, etc) using http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions.

Comment: Checking your solution, gimme some time.

Comment: Actually I can't manage to get manual loading working (I haven't much time to spend on it), so I guess that I have to accept suggestions on using GLEW and similar stuff.